# How to increase a maximum packet size for UDP?

Tags: c++, udp

I am usually sending packets that range from 3 to 15 KB but from time to time I need to send a large packet which is about 0.8-0.9 MB. In that case the UDP socket will stop because there is probably some limit on a single packet size.

How can I increase this limit so I can send large packets?

Comment: The practical limit for the data length which is imposed by the underlying IPv4 protocol is 65,507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header).   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: You should be careful when sending large frames.  Most exhcange protocols never send > 1000 bytes in a single frame because if the frame is bigger than the MTU, then it could get chopped up on the wire.  If it gets chopped up, it costs more to reassemble them, and introduces a weak link int he chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `length` field in the UDP packet header is only 16 bits in width; you can't have a single UDP packet larger than 65,535 bytes (that includes the header, too, so really the limit is 65,527 bytes; it's probably even lower still since IP has other restrictions).

Comment: That's weird. I had no problem with some packets that had around 30-35KB. They all got through.

Comment: I know. But you mentioned that actual limit is really closer to 16,527 bytes.

Comment: So I guess I will have to divide that large packet into many small ones.

Comment: @Richard: 16,527 was a typo. As James notes (but doesn't give the  specific number for), the real limit is 65,507 because of the 20 byte IP header.

Comment: @Michael: Oh. `/facepalm`. Thank you.  @Richard:  My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

note that UDP packets bigger than the MTU's (at every hope between your hosts) will be split by IP.  If a single one of these parts is lost, the whole UDP packet will be discarded.  There's no retransmission.

On a local LAN, with low traffic you might not note the difference, but in any not-so-ideal situation, it could be a huge performance hit.

I think it would be much better to either:

- use TCP for anything bigger than a few KB's
- split your messages (you'll find pretty soon you're reinventing TCP)
- use some other well-tested protocol on top of UDP.  One example is [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to use packets >64K, despite the size limitation of fields in the layer-4 headers. See **IPv6 Jumbograms**.