# How to create a large packet size in the application layer above UDP/TCP in INET?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I would like to create a large packet in the application layer of INET and I need some help.

I found some showcases and information in [Applications](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-apps.html) from the INET user guide. However, most applications are TCP or UDP applications, which means the maximum packet length is 65535 bytes per packet according to [How to increase a maximum packet size for UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549000/how-to-increase-a-maximum-packet-size-for-udp)

My question is: **How can I set the packet length to, for example, 1MB on an application layer? Does INET have an existing module above the UDP layer? Or is there an UDP application module allowing a large packet size?**

I also found some information about [Active Souce](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/queueing/doc/ActiveSourcePassiveSink.html) in the tutorials, but I am not sure if the module supports large packet sizes, and how it can integrate with the UDP applications.

I would appreciate any input.
Thank you and best regards,

Comment: Since UDP is entirely stateless and doesn't guarantee ordering of packets, it doesn't make sense for "the UDP layer to segment the packet". That segmentation would necessarily have to be some protocol *on top of* UDP - for instance, QUIC, developed for HTTP/3. With TCP, you could have a series of packets with guaranteed order, but that still only gives you a segmented *stream*, not a higher-level packet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to send very big data over UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273196/is-it-possible-to-send-very-big-data-over-udp)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Now I understand that my application needs to split for the UDP. 
However, I am not sure how to implement it in INET.
Do I need to add an additional layer? or there is an option to replace the UDP application. (for example, "UdpSourceApp")

Answer (score 0):

Fragment/defragment your application layer data and send only less than 64K sized UDP packets. In reality, a 64K packet will also be fragmented by the IP layer (and any loss of a fragment will cause the drop of the whole UDP packet).

In reality, you application generates data with some time distribution. The fact that you want to send BIG packets, just means that the application generates data in bursts where the amount of data in a burst is >64KB.

Comment: Thank you @Rudi, for the reply.
I would further ask for that how I can config my .ini file.
For example:
`
*.standardHost.app[0].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.standardHost.app[0].source.packetLength = 1MB
*.standardHost.app[0].source.productionInterval = 10ms
`
The above code doesn't work. How can I configure an application bust for 1MB?

Comment: Just as an example to Rudi's answer: when you stream 4k video over webrtc, having like 15 Mbps rate or so, all the RTP packets at the application level are nevertheless set by the protocol to be not higher than 1200 BYTES. That is made to control the stability of webrtc-connection measurements (sender and receiver RTCP reports).